Variable file path on csv import
I am importing a CSV file daily. The package currently runs as expected with the static path. The problem is that the name of the csv file changes daily so a static file path doesn't work. I basically want \somefilepath*.csv
I am new to SSIS so have followed the instructions in other articles, but they seem to only give me partial answers. I tried using a variable - again, partial answers, I tried a file system task but I don't see anything about importing a file. I also tried a script task but don't know anything about C#.
Everything I try results in failed executions.

You can create a for each loop in SSIS and loop through all files in the directory, if only one it will pick up only one.  In the loop it will find all file names and put the file name in a variable that you then use in the import for your file.

I added a screenshot. So in the foreach loop, I added a Foreach File Enumerator to the path I want with all files (.). Then a variable mapping called csvfilename which I put in the connection string of my import task. Right now I have 2 files named differently in my folder, I get an error on the second one that says "the system cannot find the file specified". Any ideas?

@DanicaMattson it sounds like you have set the variable value with a default value of one of the files, but the foreach file enumerator is not setting the value of the variable.  Please make sure that you have set csvfilename in the Variable Mappings tab of the foreach container.  If this is not the problem, please share some screenshots of the configuration.
